# How can I determine when to break my fast while traveling?

Tags: sawm, travelling

I am fasting and I have to go to another city, so my iftar will be during the journey. **My question is how can I break my fast while traveling** because I know timing of iftar in my city but I don't know what will be the time of iftar when i am on the way and how could I calculate it?

I am traveling through road but please also mention if a person is traveling by air or any other transportation.

Comment: In a plane it could be indeed difficult, but a traveling person is not necessary asked to fast.

Comment: You could check a prayer (time) chart of your destination, Else you should learn to rercognise the signs for maghtib.

Comment: can i predict it from sun set

Comment: but problem in that is people are not expert in that now a days

Comment: I think maghrib is among the easiest timings to recognise. But up in the sky it seems to me difficult.